# Convert Free space in to percentage Windows C++

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi

I need to find available free space in a drive, I have the following code, but no idea how to covert it to percentage,

```
 QString drive = "C:/";
 LPCTSTR         lpDirectoryName = (const wchar_t*)drive.utf16();
 ULARGE_INTEGER lpFreeBytesAvailable;
 ULARGE_INTEGER lpTotalNumberOfBytes;
 ULARGE_INTEGER lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes;
 BOOL  val =  GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(lpDirectoryName,&lpFreeBytesAvailable,&lpTotalNumberOfBytes,&lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes);
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Thanks in advance,
Haris

Comment: Apparently the problem is which of "free bytes available" and "total number of free bytes" to use. For that, I suggest checking the **documentation**. And perhaps a requirements specification, if there is one.

Comment: Basically what I need is check freespace available in drive and if it less than a threshold clear some directory from my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account user quota's (recommended), you should do the following:

```
double percent_free = 100.0 *(double)lpFreeBytesAvailable.QuadPart / (double)lpTotalNumberOfBytes.QuadPart
```

If user quotas are disabled (most systems), this stil lworks as the whole drive is used.

Note that your code will compile only in Unicode builds. It's better to write it as:

```
BOOL val =  GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(_T("C:/"),&lpFreeBytesAvailable,&lpTotalNumberOfBytes,&lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I didn't  get `your code will compile only in Unicode builds` actually I am running it from Qt Creator and my drive will be from a QString.

Comment: `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` is a macro that can translate to `GetDiskFreeSpaceExA` or `GetDiskFreeSpaceExW` depending on the build type (unicode/ansi). the _T macro will create the string literal to match.

Comment: I got error when using both of the above  `'type cast' : cannot convert from 'ULARGE_INTEGER' to 'double'` and `'_T': identifier not found`

Comment: I fixed the code. ULARGE_INTEGER is a union... _T is declared in TCHAR.h. You can leave your code as is with respect to unicode. this was just a remark. In Qt, it's better to use unicode as unicode is natural to Qt.

Comment: You should not rely on TCHAR macros anymore.  Pass the return value of `QString.utf16()` directly to `GetDiskFreeSpaceExW()`.  If you want to pass a literal instead, use `L"C:/"`.

Comment: It is certainly not better to use TCHAR. In many cases the best decision is to simply target Unicode.